# Fix ScrollView on small scroll, React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have a ScrollView and I want it to scroll only to top and bottom, I have done it depending on it's position when `onTouchEnd` happens. But I need to scroll to certain point where it scrolls to bottom or top. Can I do the same when I do small and sharp scroll?
here's my code

```
  const [scrollToTop, setScrollToTop] = useState(false)
  const scrollViewRef = useRef()

  const handleGestureEvent = (e) => {
    if (e?.nativeEvent?.contentOffset?.y > 120) {
      setScrollToTop(false)
    } else { 
      setScrollToTop(true)
    }
  }

  const fixScrollView = () => { 
    if (scrollViewRef && scrollViewRef.current) {
      if (scrollToTop) {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({y: 0, animated: true})
      } else {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true})
      }
    }
  }
  <ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  onScroll={handleGestureEvent}
  onTouchEnd={fixScrollView}></ScrollView>
```

But now I need to scroll to certain point on the screen where it scrolls to top or bottom. I don't know, is there a way to determine small and sharp scroll so that the list would scroll to bottom or top when it occurs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - show us some code so we can help better

Answer (score 1):

You can run the "scrollTo" method of the ScrollView. Check out the source.

You can get reference the ScrollView component by setting ref property and using this.refs as described here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html